# Collisions aren't registering with Python Turtles

Tags: python, python-3.6, collision, turtle-graphics

I'm creating a simple 2D shooter following an online tutorial, and the enemy sprites (except 1, there are 5 total) are not abiding by my collision code. Everything works except the bullet object that the player controls simply passes right through the enemy sprites. Error messages I received:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Python\Python36\pygame projects\space invaders.py", line 163, in <module>
        bullet.hideturtle()
      File "C:\Python\Python36\lib\turtle.py", line 2322, in hideturtle
        self.pen(shown=False)
      File "C:\Python\Python36\lib\turtle.py", line 2459, in pen
        self._update()
      File "C:\Python\Python36\lib\turtle.py", line 2660, in _update
        self._update_data()
      File "C:\Python\Python36\lib\turtle.py", line 2646, in _update_data
        self.screen._incrementudc()
      File "C:\Python\Python36\lib\turtle.py", line 1292, in _incrementudc
        raise Terminator
    turtle.Terminator
```

If you skim through the code half way you'll find the Pythagoras theory I used for the collision math, unsure if it's correct or not:

```
enemies = []
number_of_enemies = 5
for i in range(number_of_enemies):
    enemies.append(turtle.Turtle())

for enemy in enemies:
    enemy.color("green")
    enemy.shape("circle")
    enemy.penup()
    enemy.speed(0)
    x = random.randint(-200, 200)
    y = random.randint(100, 250)
    enemy.setposition(x, y)

enemyspeed = 2

def isCollision(t1, t2):
    distance = math.sqrt(math.pow(t1.xcor() - t2.xcor(), 2)+ math.pow(t1.ycor() - t2.ycor(), 2))
    if distance < 15:
        return True
    else:
        return False



while True:

for enemy in enemies:
    x = enemy.xcor()
    x += enemyspeed
    enemy.setx(x)

    if enemy.xcor() > 280:
        for e in enemies:
            y = enemy.ycor()
            y -= 40
            enemy.sety(y)
        enemyspeed *= -1

    if enemy.xcor() < -280:
        for e in enemies:
            y = enemy.ycor()
            y -= 40
            enemy.sety(y)
        enemyspeed *= -1

    if bulletstate == "fire":
        y = bullet.ycor()
        y += bulletspeed
        bullet.sety(y)

    if isCollision(bullet, enemy):
        #reset the bullet
        bullet.hideturtle()
        bulletstate = "ready"
        bullet.setposition(0, -400)
        #reset the enemy
        x = random.randint(-200, 200)
        y = random.randint(100, 250)
        enemy.setposition(x, y)

    if isCollision(player, enemy):
        player.hideturtle()
        enemy.hideturtle()
        print ("Get To The Doctors! You're Riddled!")
        break
```

Apologies if the answer is blatantly obvious. I would be grateful for the time anyone spends explaining the error. Others have posted similar questions, but every one has examples which apply to them and I'm still at the stage where it is tricky for me to visualise others' examples. Any help would greatly be appreciated.

Comment: That's a lot of code and it makes it rather intimidating for anyone to take a look at your problem. Is it possible for you to trim it down to make a [MCVE] of your problem? Also, are you sure that is the entire error message? It looks like you cut off some important information at the end.

Comment: Have you tried messaging the author of the tutorial? You might get a more specific answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your primary issue is you're updating the bullet between every enemy update instead of once for all the the enemy updates.  This creates a skew between the visual and what's really happening.  Also, you don't need to define the Pythagorean formula, turtles already know it!  Below is my rework of your code to address the above and rework the the coding style and efficiency a bit:

```
from turtle import Turtle, Screen
from random import randint

NUMBER_OF_ENEMIES = 5
ENEMY_JUMP = 40

BULLET_SPEED = 20
PLAYER_SPEED = 15

SAFETY_DISTANCE = 15

GALLERY_WIDTH, GALLERY_HEIGHT = 560, 550
GALLERY_BORDER = 80

# player movement
def move_left():
    x = player.xcor() - PLAYER_SPEED

    if x < -GALLERY_WIDTH / 2:
        x = -GALLERY_WIDTH / 2

    player.setx(x)

def move_right():
    x = player.xcor() + PLAYER_SPEED

    if x > GALLERY_WIDTH / 2:
        x = GALLERY_WIDTH / 2

    player.setx(x)

def fire_bullet():
    global bulletstate

    if bulletstate == 'ready':
        bulletstate = 'fire'
        bullet.setposition(player.position())
        bullet.forward(BULLET_SPEED / 2)
        bullet.showturtle()

def isCollision(t1, t2):
    return t1.distance(t2) < SAFETY_DISTANCE

def move():
    global enemy_speed, bulletstate

    screen.tracer(False)

    for enemy in enemies:
        x = enemy.xcor() + enemy_speed

        enemy.setx(x)

        if x > GALLERY_WIDTH / 2:
            for e in enemies:
                y = e.ycor() - ENEMY_JUMP
                e.sety(y)

            enemy_speed *= -1

        elif x < -GALLERY_WIDTH / 2:
            for e in enemies:
                y = e.ycor() - ENEMY_JUMP
                e.sety(y)

            enemy_speed *= -1

        if isCollision(player, enemy):
            player.hideturtle()
            enemy.hideturtle()
            print("Get To The Doctors! You're Riddled!")
            screen.update()
            return

        if isCollision(bullet, enemy):
            # reset the bullet
            bullet.hideturtle()
            bullet.setposition(0, -GALLERY_HEIGHT)
            bulletstate = 'ready'

            # reset the enemy
            enemy.hideturtle()
            x = randint(GALLERY_BORDER - GALLERY_WIDTH / 2, GALLERY_WIDTH / 2 - GALLERY_BORDER)
            y = randint(GALLERY_HEIGHT / 2 - 175, GALLERY_HEIGHT / 2 - 25)
            enemy.setposition(x, y)
            enemy.showturtle()

    if bulletstate == 'fire':
        bullet.forward(BULLET_SPEED)

        # check to see if the bullets has gone to the top
        if bullet.ycor() > GALLERY_HEIGHT / 2:
            bullet.hideturtle()
            bulletstate = 'ready'

    screen.tracer(True)

    screen.ontimer(move, 25)

screen = Screen()
screen.setup(GALLERY_WIDTH + GALLERY_BORDER, GALLERY_HEIGHT + GALLERY_BORDER)
screen.bgcolor('black')

player = Turtle('turtle', visible=False)
player.speed('fastest')
player.color('red')
player.penup()
player.setheading(90)
player.sety(-250)  # need to define this
player.showturtle()

enemies = []

enemy_speed = 1

for _ in range(NUMBER_OF_ENEMIES):
    enemy = Turtle('circle', visible=False)
    enemy.speed('fastest')
    enemy.color('green')
    enemy.penup()

    x = randint(GALLERY_BORDER - GALLERY_WIDTH / 2, GALLERY_WIDTH / 2 - GALLERY_BORDER)
    y = randint(GALLERY_HEIGHT / 2 - 175, GALLERY_HEIGHT / 2 - 25)  # define these!
    enemy.setposition(x, y)
    enemy.showturtle()

    enemies.append(enemy)

# create the player's spunk shots
bullet = Turtle('triangle', visible=False)
bullet.speed('fastest')
bullet.shapesize(0.5)
bullet.color('white')
bullet.penup()
bullet.setheading(90)

# define bullet state
# ready - ready to fire
# fire - bullet is firing
bulletstate = 'ready'

screen.onkey(move_left, 'Left')
screen.onkey(move_right, 'Right')
screen.onkey(fire_bullet, 'space')

screen.listen()

move()

screen.mainloop()
```

I guessed at the missing pieces.  See how this plays for you.

Comment: That has solved the issue! Thank you very much. Makes far more sense to me now.