# Python Turtle module hideturtle() isn't working

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

I am writing the [Space Invaders game from Christian Thompson](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UC2vm-0XX5RkWCXWwtBZGOXg)
I have problem exactly in line 188 where the player and enemy hide when a collision is detected. My player turtle is hiding but the enemy turtle doesn't "want" to hide.  Here is the code:

```
import turtle
import os
import math
import random
import winsound

#Set up the screen
wn = turtle.Screen()
wn.bgcolor("black")
wn.title("Space Invaders")
wn.bgpic("space_invaders_background.gif")

#Register the shapes
turtle.register_shape("invader.gif")
turtle.register_shape("player.gif")

#Draw border
border_pen = turtle.Turtle()
border_pen.speed(0)
border_pen.color("white")
border_pen.penup()
border_pen.setposition(-300,-300)
border_pen.pendown()
border_pen.pensize(3)
for side in range(4):
    border_pen.fd(600)
    border_pen.lt(90)
border_pen.hideturtle()

#Set the score to 0
score = 0

#Draw score
score_pen = turtle.Turtle()
score_pen.speed(0)
score_pen.color("white")
score_pen.penup()
score_pen.setposition(-290, 280)
scorestring = "Score: %s" %score
score_pen.write(scorestring, False, align="left", font=("Arial", 14, "normal"))
score_pen.hideturtle()

#Game Over
game_over = turtle.Turtle()
game_over.speed(0)
game_over.color("red")
game_over.penup()
game_over.setposition(0, 0)
gameOverMsg = "Game Over!"
game_over.hideturtle()


#Create player
player = turtle.Turtle()
player.color("blue")
player.shape("player.gif")
player.penup()
player.speed(0)
player.setposition(0,-230)
player.setheading(90)

playerspeed = 15


#Choose a number of enemies
number_of_enemies = 20
#Create empty list of enemies
enemies = []

#Add enemies to list
for i in range(number_of_enemies):
    # Create the enemy
    enemies.append(turtle.Turtle())

for enemy in enemies:
    enemy.color("red")
    enemy.shape("invader.gif")
    enemy.penup()
    enemy.speed(0)
    x = random.randint(-200, 200)
    y = random.randint(100, 250)
    enemy.setposition(x, y)

enemyspeed = number_of_enemies * 0.5

#Create the player's bullet
bullet = turtle.Turtle()
bullet.color("yellow")
bullet.shape("triangle")
bullet.penup()
bullet.speed(0)
bullet.setheading(90)
bullet.shapesize(0.5, 0.5)
bullet.hideturtle()

bulletspeed = 20

def laser():
    winsound.PlaySound("laser.wav", winsound.SND_ASYNC)
def explosion():
    winsound.PlaySound("explosion.wav", winsound.SND_ASYNC)

#Move the player left and right
def move_left():
    x = player.xcor()
    x -= playerspeed
    if x < -280:
        x = -280
    player.setx(x)

def move_right():
    x = player.xcor()
    x += playerspeed
    if x > 280:
        x = 280
    player.setx(x)

def fire_bullet():
    if not bullet.isvisible():
        laser()
        #Move the bullet to the just above the player
        x = player.xcor()
        y = player.ycor() + 10
        bullet.setposition(x, y)
        bullet.showturtle()

#Checking collision between enemy and bullet
def isCollision(t1, t2) :
    distance = math.sqrt(math.pow(t1.xcor()-t2.xcor(),2)+math.pow(t1.ycor()-t2.ycor(),2))
    if distance < 20:
        return True
    else:
        return False

#Create keyboard bindings
turtle.listen()
turtle.onkeypress(move_left, "Left")
turtle.onkeypress(move_right, "Right")
turtle.onkeypress(fire_bullet, "space")

#Main game loop
while True:

    for enemy in enemies:
        #Move the enemy
        x = enemy.xcor()
        x += enemyspeed
        enemy.setx(x)

        #Move the enemy back and down
        if enemy.xcor() > 280:
            #Move all enemies down
            for e in enemies:
                y = e.ycor()
                y -= 40
                e.sety(y)
            #Change enemy direction
            enemyspeed *= -1

        if enemy.xcor() < -280:
            #Move all enemies down
            for e in enemies:
                y = e.ycor()
                y -= 40
                e.sety(y)
            #Change enemy direction
            enemyspeed *= -1

        # Check for a collision between the bullet and the enemy
        if isCollision(bullet, enemy):
            explosion()
            # Reset the bullet
            bullet.hideturtle()
            bullet.setposition(0, -400)
            # Reset the enemy
            x = random.randint(-200, 200)
            y = random.randint(100, 250)
            enemy.setposition(x, y)
            #Update the score
            score += 10
            scorestring = "Score: %s" %score
            score_pen.clear()
            score_pen.write(scorestring, False, align="left", font=("Arial", 14, "normal"))

        if isCollision(player, enemy):
            explosion()
            player.hideturtle()
            enemy.hideturtle()
            game_over.write(gameOverMsg, False, align="center", font=("Arial", 60, "normal"))
            break

    #Move the bullet
    if bullet.isvisible():
        y = bullet.ycor()
        y += bulletspeed
        bullet.sety(y)

    #Check border collision
    if bullet.ycor() > 290:
        bullet.hideturtle()








wn.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't able to reproduce your problem.  I've reworked your code below: I've dropped the images and sound so anyone can run it and help you debug it; I tossed your `isCollision()` code and substituted turtle's own `distance()` method; I replaced the `while True:` loop, which has no place in an event-driven world like turtle, with a timer event; I've streamlined the code where I could:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle
from random import randint

PLAYER_SPEED = 15
BULLET_SPEED = 20

# Choose a number of enemies
NUMBER_OF_ENEMIES = 20

SMALL_FONT = ('Arial', 14, 'normal')
LARGE_FONT = ('Arial', 60, 'normal')

# Move the player left and right
def move_left():
    x = player.xcor() - PLAYER_SPEED

    if x < -280:
        x = -280

    player.setx(x)

def move_right():
    x = player.xcor() + PLAYER_SPEED

    if x > 280:
        x = 280

    player.setx(x)

def fire_bullet():
    if not bullet.isvisible():
        # Move the bullet to the just above the player
        x, y = player.position()
        bullet.setposition(x, y + 10)
        bullet.showturtle()

# Check collision between enemy and bullet
def isCollision(t1, t2):
    return t1.distance(t2) < 20

# Set up the screen
wn = Screen()
wn.bgcolor('black')
wn.title("Space Invaders")

# Draw border
border_pen = Turtle(visible=False)
border_pen.speed('fastest')
border_pen.color('white')
border_pen.pensize(3)

border_pen.penup()
border_pen.setposition(-300, -300)
border_pen.pendown()

for _ in range(4):
    border_pen.fd(600)
    border_pen.lt(90)

# Set the score to 0
score = 0

# Draw score
score_pen = Turtle(visible=False)
score_pen.speed('fastest')
score_pen.color('white')
score_pen.penup()

score_pen.setposition(-290, 280)
scorestring = "Score: %s" % score
score_pen.write(scorestring, False, align='left', font=SMALL_FONT)

# Game Over
game_over = Turtle(visible=False)
game_over.speed('fastest')
game_over.color('red')
game_over.penup()
gameOverMsg = "Game Over!"

# Create player
player = Turtle('turtle')
player.speed('fastest')
player.color('blue')
player.penup()
player.setposition(0, -230)
player.setheading(90)

# Create empty list of enemies
enemies = []

# Add enemies to list
for _ in range(NUMBER_OF_ENEMIES):
    # Create the enemy
    enemy = Turtle('turtle', visible=False)
    enemy.settiltangle(270)  # for non GIF version of game
    enemy.speed('fastest')
    enemy.color('red')
    enemy.penup()
    enemy.setposition(randint(-200, 200), randint(100, 250))

    enemies.append(enemy)

for enemy in enemies:
    enemy.showturtle()

# Create the player's bullet
bullet = Turtle('triangle', visible=False)
bullet.color('yellow')
bullet.penup()
bullet.speed('fastest')
bullet.setheading(90)
bullet.shapesize(0.5)

# Create keyboard bindings
wn.onkeypress(move_left, 'Left')
wn.onkeypress(move_right, 'Right')
wn.onkeypress(fire_bullet, 'space')
wn.listen()

enemy_speed = NUMBER_OF_ENEMIES * 0.5

# Main game loop
def move():
    global score, enemy_speed

    collision = False

    for enemy in enemies:

        # Move the enemy
        enemy.forward(enemy_speed)

        # Check for a collision between the bullet and the enemy
        if isCollision(bullet, enemy):
            # Reset the bullet
            bullet.hideturtle()
            # Reset the enemy
            enemy.setposition(randint(-200, 200), randint(100, 250))
            # Update the score
            score += 10
            scorestring = "Score: %s" % score
            score_pen.clear()
            score_pen.write(scorestring, False, align='left', font=SMALL_FONT)

        if isCollision(player, enemy):
            player.hideturtle()
            enemy.hideturtle()
            game_over.write(gameOverMsg, False, align='center', font=LARGE_FONT)
            collision = True
            break

    if any(enemy.xcor() < -280 or enemy.xcor() > 280 for enemy in enemies):
        # Move all enemies down
        for enemy in enemies:
            enemy.sety(enemy.ycor() - 40)

        # Change enemy direction
        enemy_speed *= -1

    # Move the bullet
    if bullet.isvisible():
        bullet.forward(BULLET_SPEED)
        # Check border collision
        if bullet.ycor() > 290:
            bullet.hideturtle()

    if not collision:
        wn.ontimer(move, 50)

move()

wn.mainloop()
```

This program is déjà vu for me [with respect to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50510385/5771269) so see [my answer to it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50514807/5771269) for more ideas.  Also, see this answer to [another space invaders game in turtle](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52437751/5771269) to see what you can learn from it to polish your game.